# How to pass dynamic host ips in ansible playbook extension in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ansible, ansible-inventory

How to pass dynamic host ips in ansible playbook extension in azure devops.
I am using Ansible extension in azure devops release pipeline and i want to pass dynamic list of IPs 
from a previous task in Host inventory.

Comment: Hi Did you check out below answer? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define a variable and assign the list of IPs to it in the previous task. Then you can retrieve the list of IPs by referring to the variable in Ansible tasks.

Use expression `"##vso[task.setvariable variable=IPs]ip1,ip2,ip3"` to define a variable and assign value to it, Please  check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts). Below is an example to set the ips to the variable IPs in a powershell task.

[image]

Then you can use the variable like below example in Ansible task.

[image]

If the list of IPs is the output variables from previous you can directly refer to it using this expression `$(<ReferenceName>.<VariableName>)`. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#use-output-variables-from-tasks) for output variables. If the previous task didnot output the variable for IPs, then you need follow above steps to define a variable for it.